# How we can update two collection in one query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models one is products with this attributes

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const salesSchema =new mongoose.Schema({
    productname:{
        type:String,
        required:trud,
        unique:true
},
    productCount:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("products",salesSchema);
```

and sales with this attributes

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const salesSchema =new mongoose.Schema({
    productId:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"products",
},
    salesCount:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("sales",salesSchema);
```

when some one act with sales it should decrease or increase automatically update the  count product table.

Answer (score 1):

Yo can only run a query against one collection at any given time. So you have to do those queries separately. However, if you're using MongoDB Atlas for hosting, you can use their [Trigger](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/triggers/) functionality to listen to changes to your sales collection. When an insert is triggered, run a query towards products where you reduce the quantity.

If you're not using Atlas you can use [MongoDB Change Streams](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/javascript/nodejs-change-streams-triggers/) available via the Node SDK to do the same thing as triggers, listen to inserts to a specific collection. (You can do this on any environment, however you need to configure a [Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/#procedure) for this to work)

So what I'm saying is; Only insert the sales document, and let a watcher handle the product collection updates after.

```js
const changeStream = salesSchema.collection.watch([{
    $match: {
        operationType: 'insert',
    },
}], {
    fullDocument: 'updateLookup',
})

changeStream.on('change', changeEvent => {
    const salesDocument = changeEvent.fullDocument

    // Run the product update here
})
```